# Is there a way to achieve a sort of placeholder for Python object attributes?

Tags: python, attributes

Hoping someone can help me with just pseudocode. I can't copy the code here as it's not entirely my own.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
for result in results_set:
    if conditionA:
            # When conditionA is true, test on this_attribute.
            if result.this_attribute == "interesting string":
                    # do things.
            if result.this_attribute == "another interesting string"
                    # do different things.

    else:
            # ConditionA is false? Test on that_other_attribute instead.
            if result.that_other_attribute == "interesting string"
                    # do the same exact things as above for "interesting string"
            if result.that_other_attribute == "another interesting string"
                    # do the same exact things as above for "another interesting string"
```

It seems very inefficient to have the test for conditionA or conditionB be *inside* the for loop since I deal with results_sets that can be thousands of lines long. Plus the code looks bad because I'm just repeating myself.

Feels like I should be able to test for conditionA / B before the loop takes place, and tell Python what attribute of "result" to compare next based on that test.

Which attribute I test will always depend on the value of ConditionA. I may end up with a ConditionB, C or D in the near future as well which will require checking on a third, fourth or fifth attribute of *result*.

Currently I solved this by having two nearly identical functions that each have their own "for" without the ConditionA test inside it... but that looks bad and will become a nightmare when B, C or D roll around.

Is it possible to have an attribute placeholder somehow? If so, how please?

---

Edit:

I am trying to achieve something like this....

```
result = a filler value used only to reference attribute names

if ConditionA:
    check_attribute = result.this_attribute
else:
    check_attribute = result.that_other_attribute

for result in results_set:
    if check_attribute == "interesting string":
        # do things.
    if check_attribute == "another interesting string"
        # do different things.
```

Comment: There is `getattr(result, "this_attribute")` but this may be not so efficient.

Comment: I thought getattr(result, "this_attribute") would point to the value of this_attribute though, which would change at every loop? Is there anything that could hold the name of the attribute for example, which won't change?

Comment: Yah, so the solution would be to hold the string value **outside** the loop, and then using getattr **inside** the loop. See my answer below. As for the edit, my answer addresses this issue of a placeholder.

Comment: Ok I didn't connect the dots at all, my apologies, But yeah this looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using getattrs might get you somewhere here, however unlikely that may sound. Right above the for loop, you could do

```
value_to_check = "this_attribute" if conditionA else "that_other_attribute".
```

Yes, those were **strings**. 
Next, in the `for` loop, you could do

```
result_value = getattr (result, value_to_check)
if result_value == "interesting string": #thing to do
elif result_value == "another interesting string": #other thing to do
```